Why don't we observe protons deflecting in J.J. Thomson's experiment?
I have been told that in J.J. Thomson's experiment of the discovery of the electron, he took 2 metal plates, an anode and a cathode, put them in a CRT, and then supplied a high voltage with opposite charges on the 2 plates (subject to very low pressure). Now at such a pressure the gas becomes conducting so the circuit is complete and the inner side of the tube is coated with a fluorescent material. This glows when the current is supplied and the electrons are fired in the cathode ray.
When he applied a magnetic and electric field, in both cases, the beam deflected of to a side, showing the presence of negatively charged particles.
My question is, that if the anode was simultaneously also firing an anode ray containing protons, why don't we see it deflecting to the opposite direction when applying a magnetic or electric field? Why is it that the proton deflection is only observed on perforating the cathode?
PS: If anything is wrong in my prerequisites, please remark.

Most people would call it a physical experiment.

If the equipment is accelerating electrons it isn’t accelerating protons. Protons will bend, but note the large mass difference - the deflection of the protons would be reduced by that ratio.

@JonCuster No. The electrostatic deflection scales as $1/E$, so a 1 keV electron and 1 keV proton will deflect the same! For magnetic fields it's $1/p$ or $1/\sqrt{mE}$ or about 43 times less deflection for the proton vs electron at the same acceleration energy. I'm a bit rusty but I think these are correct.

@uhoh But a proton with 1keV will travel a lot more slowly than an electron with the same energy. Your answer is only right when considering setups that guarantees particles with the same kinetic energy which isn't the way these experiments are set up.

I think there's already too much q. about this experiment here, and they're all more appropriate for hsm.se

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/108454/why-did-j-j-thomson-observe-protons-in-his-cathode-ray-experiment https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/164192/observation-of-deflection-in-the-cathode-ray-experiment https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/105536/how-did-j-j-thomson-prove-that-the-cathode-rays-were-made-of-negative-particle https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/182701/perforated-cathode-in-anode-ray-experiment

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/146934/why-is-it-that-protons-and-electrons-undergo-the-same-amount-of-deflection-in-an

@matt_black Now I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what Thomson did. If he used each field separately, then what I wrote is fine. If He turned both on at the same time and made a velocity filter then your point about speed makes sense. However, the speeds sill differ by that factor of 43 (the square root of the mass ratio), so John Custer's would be reduced by that ratio is still wrong

the answer is that they were not looking for the protons or other + particles; the conditions are simply different. The protons re effectively in different places, require different fields and have smaller deflections so it helps to isolate the stream. Similar to mass spectrometry where the negative ions are ignored.

In a CRT, when a sufficiently high voltage is applied, only electrons are emitted from the cathode's surface. These electrons then travel from the cathode to the anode. As these electrons collide with gas molecules in the CRT, they ionize the gas molecules, thereby generating anode rays. These anode rays are not protons (except in the case of hydrogen gas in the tube); rather, they are positively charged cations. These cations are then attracted to the cathode. Although it might seem that they are generated at the anode, they are actually formed in the middle section between the electrodes, as a result of the collision between cathode rays and gas molecules.
Now you are asking if cathode is emitting electrons, they why anode is not emitting protons. The reason for this is that in any atom, lets say metallic atom of cathode, most loosely bound particles are electrons. Protons are held very strongly inside the nucleus. This is because electrons are held inside an atom via an Electromagnetic Force whereas protons are held inside an atom via a Strong Nuclear Force. Strong Nuclear Force is way stronger than Electromagnetic Force. Therefore it is not possible to remove protons from an atom without a nuclear reaction that requires a lot of energy.
Therefore, in a CRT, when electric potential is applied, only electrons are removed from cathode's metal atoms. While protons are held strongly inside the nucleus via Strong Nuclear Force.
EDIT 1: No, this does not mean that this experiment only works for hydrogen. What I was saying is that in a CRT, the anode is not 'firing' anything. Only the cathode emits electrons that move towards the anode. On their way to the anode, these electrons collide with the gas molecules present inside the CRT, ionizing them. These ionized gas molecules are called anode rays. However, these anode rays do not originate from the anode. Instead, they are created in the region between the two electrodes. Because these ionized gas molecules are positively charged, they are attracted towards the cathode.
If hydrogen gas is filled inside the CRT, the electrons emitted from the cathode will ionize the hydrogen gas. When hydrogen molecules lose their electrons, they are converted into protons. Protons are only produced if hydrogen gas is used, and these protons do not originate from the anode. If any other gas, such as oxygen, is used, the electrons will ionize the oxygen gas, forming oxygen cations. In this case, these cations will be called anode rays. In short, anode rays are just ionized form of the gas that is filled inside the CRT.
Edit 2: It will be very difficult for someone to observe the deflection of both cathode rays and anode rays in the middle of the discharge tube. The reason is that cathode rays originate from the cathode, and anode rays originate in the region between the two electrodes. When you apply an electric field to the middle section, you disrupt the path of the electrons. The cathode rays (electrons) will be attracted towards the positive plate. This will limit the supply of electrons to the region closer to the anode. Due to the limited supply of high-energy electrons, the gas molecules in that region will be less likely to ionize. This means there will be less ionization of gas molecules in the region closer to the anode and relatively more ionization of gas molecules in the region closer to the cathode. To observe a deflection in anode rays, the anode rays must ideally come from the region closer to the anode and then follow a straight path towards the cathode. But now, due to the deflection of cathode rays, anode rays originate in the region closer to the cathode. Therefore, there is a very short distance between this region and the cathode. As a result, it will be very difficult to observe the deflection of anode rays due to their very short path.

Well, does that mean that the E. Goldstein Experiment of the discovery of proton works only in the case of hydrogen.

I'll edit my answer to add this explanation.

So, in the case of hydrogen, where the ionised form of the gas is basically a proton, why does it deflect only after crossing the perforation, why not in the middle where the electrons are being deflected?

I'll update my answer again to add a detailed explanation for this as well.

Please provide the source of your answer.

The question is reasonable, and there are a few things that explain why we do not speak of "anode rays", or "proton guns", but rather cathode rays and electron guns.

Atoms of metals are held tightly in place.  Though an individual electron is easily removed from the atoms (after, all, metals are a sea of mobile electrons), the protons are bound by nuclear forces, and the nucleus and remaining, non-conductance band, electrons are bound in a crystal structure.

Electrons are light compared to the massive nucleus. For example, an average tungsten atom has 74 protons, 110 neutrons and 74 electrons. Each proton or neutron is about 1,800 times more massive than an electron. There are about 184 nucleons in a tungsten atom, so the nucleus is about 33,000 more massive than one electron. That is not too far from the ratio of mass of an automobile to a tennis ball. Swat the ball with a racket, and it moves quite fast. The car would accelerate much less with the same swat.
One exception would be a plasma of pure hydrogen (no deuterium or tritium), in which case one could speak meaningfully of "protons" moving, as opposed to ionized atoms. However, on the average, the electrons are moving 1,800 times faster than the protons.


However, there are ways to accelerate ions.

In an ionized very low pressure gas (plasma), electrons hurtle towards the positive electrode while heavier positive gas ions waddle towards the negative.

Field emission can rip particles off a sharpened metal needle, e.g., adsorbed helium from a tungsten or platinum tip. Field ion microscopy (FIM) was one of the first methods to directly visualize the crystal structure of metals.

Plasma and LASER wakefield acceleration can boost ions to relativistic velocity in just a few centimeters.
And then there was the primeval soup, virtually a sea of croutons...



@wizzwizz4, Oops.. fumble-fingered "electron" for "electrode".  [BTW, I avoided "cathode" and "anode" because of possible confusion in usage in battery, diodes and plating.]


My question is, that if the anode was simultaneously also firing an
anode ray containing protons, why don't we see it deflecting to the
opposite direction when applying a magnetic or electric field? Why is
it that the proton deflection is only observed on perforating the
cathode?

Keep in mind, the historical success of cathode ray tubes was based on the development of ingenious high vacuum generation methods, only then one could see the electron flow. There is a directionality of the current even in the cathode ray tube. The current is carried by electrons, as it was found out later. There was no experimental sign that something was also coming from the anode (opposite direction). It is very hard to strip all the electrons from the anode material and produce naked protons. It is easy to eject electrons from metallic surfaces not protons. In short, don't assume that bare protons were also present in CRT experiments.
There are no "anode rays" in the same sense as cathode rays. The term "anode rays" or "canal rays" (Kanalstrahlen as they were originally called) refers to a different phenomenon, discovered by Eugen Goldstein. Canal rays are composed of positively charged ions (protons in the case of hydrogen gas) that are produced when the residual gas in the tube is ionized. These rays are observed when they pass through holes in the cathode.
The OP further asks:

In that case, when the protons are emitted by the ionised hydrogen
gas, why do they deflect and are observed only on passing the cathode?

Again, just a minor correction, no protons are emitted by any electrode or a gas in CRT, even when H2 is there. We are talking about two different experiments, one where there is very high vacuum, we only observe electron moving directionally. In case, when gases are present one can have a mixture of a ionized gas, hydrogen atoms, ionized hydrogen atoms, and electrons (particles soup). This experiment is carried out at relatively higher gas pressure. In this experiment, if cathode is further perforated, then you see canal rays, which are just the same positively charged ionized gas accelerating towards the cathode.

In that case, when the protons are emitted by the ionised hydrogen gas, why do they deflect and are observed only on passing the cathode?

See edits in the response.

If I'm not wrong, I checked this up and the pressure was  same in both   the experiments i.e. 0.001 mm of Hg. I don't see the difference between the two experiments except the perforations. Also, when you say ionized hydrogen gas, that is essentially protons. So why are they deflected only after crossing the perforation?

Can you provide references, it will be easier to check. You will have plenty of ionized hydrogen molecules too.
